# How to display eloquent rows within a non-blade template?

Tags: php, view, laravel-4, eloquent

I am creating a simple application with Laravel, but I would like to eliminate the use of Blade in views.

So, my question is, how can I display a particular row, or a couple of rows in a view without using Blade?

The problem is, that the `$data` parameter in `View::make('post', $data);` can be only an array, which means I cannot pass an object which is returned by `$data = Post::find(1);`.

(Let's assume that my view file is called `post.php` and my model is called `Post`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View::make('post', array(
    'result' => Post::find(1)
));
```

Then you can use `$result` in your view.
I believe you can also call `Post::find(1)` directly in your view script.

Comment: Wow, this is a great solution! Thank you!